# retain the google sheet data look

Tags: google-apps-script

the value in my google sheet cell look like this:

Thus, we discourage any staff entering the office on the said date.  We also request everyone to do the following before the February 4 spraying:

1. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
2. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.
3. There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have.

---

but when fetching google sheet data using app script the output:

Thus, we discourage any staff entering the office on the said date.  We also request everyone to do the following before the February 4 spraying:1. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 2. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.3. There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have.

how can i keep the format or look the same in google sheet

this is my code

code.gs

```
function getValues() 
{

  var spreadSheetId = "SPREADSHEETID"; //CHANGE
  var dataRange = "Query!A1:B1"; //CHANGE Data!A2:F
  var range = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadSheetId, dataRange);

  var temp = range.values;
      
  return temp;

  //Logger.log(temp);
}

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('Index')
      .evaluate();
}
```

MY INDEX.HTML

```
<body>  
  <? var temp = getValues(); ?>  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-10">
      <?= temp[0][1] ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

HTML condenses whitespace, and converts newline characters to spaces. Use the `<pre>` tag in HTML, or replace newlines in data with `<br>` tags, like this:

```
  return temp.map(value => String(value).replace('\n', '<br />\n'));
```

The code you show is not pushing the `temp` variable to the HTML template. See [Pushing variables to templates](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#pushing_variables_to_templates).

Comment: <pre> </pre> did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the solution is closer to data organization than code.

The easier and more scalable way to maintain the structure of your string is to spread it out between 4 rows; one for each block characters.

In other words, rather than pulling this data from

`getRange(1, 1)` → row 1 column 1

it would look more like

`getRange(1, 1, 4)` → row 1 column 1 down to row 4

You can view the documentation for [getRange() here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))

Other than that, you can use `getDisplayValue()`, which preserves formatting. You can read about this method more [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDisplayValue()).

Additionally, given that `getValues()` is an existing method within apps script, it would be better practice to rename your function more descriptively.

Answer (score 0):

`<pre></pre>`
did the trick